# Drupal - Change location of uploaded image in page content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have added an image upload field in the basic page content type that comes with the standard Drupal installation. If the user uploads an image, I want it to be automatically displayed at the top of the page as a banner. Problem is, the image just gets added below the main content of my page under the heading '**Page image: '**

How am I able to change the page layout so that the image is displayed where ever I want?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly there are a couple of ways to go about this. One, create your basic page content with your image and then create a view that references that image, or a bunch of images, like a slideshow, and places these images in the "banner," region of the page.
You will need to add a filter in your view to only accept the page content type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so you mean i need to use this - http://drupal.org/project/views ?? Sorry I'm new to Drupal (coming from .NET) so am finding some things hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: No problem, I started off .NET also. Yes download the recommended version of the views module into your sites/all/modules folder.  Install the modules Views and Views UI.  Under admin/structure/views create a new block view of content type basic page.  Then make it an un-ordered list of fields, uncheck the use pager button and click save and continue.  It will take you to a screen with fields, filter, and sort on the left column.  In the fields row, click add, then select your image from basic page. Click save and navigate to the blocks page to put your block in the banner region.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to hide image field from admin/structure/types/manage/page/display, which is content type's manage display page. You can do this by selecting "Hidden" option in FORMAT column for image field. This will hide your image field when you view your node.

To display image field in banner region you can create an block type view to display only image field of basic page content type and position this block to banner region. This will display all image in basic page contents. To display only current viewed content image you have to apply contextual filter with these steps:

- In edit view page click on add button in contextual filter and select
  Content: Nid option and click apply.
- Then select "Provide default value" from "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT
  AVAILABLE" and in "TYPE" field select "Content ID from URL" option and
  click on apply.

Now if you view your basic page content image will be shown in banner region instead of display with node content.